# Django admin.ModelAdmin inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-inheritance

Is it possible to **create subclasses from a Django `admin.ModelAdmin` class**?

I'm trying to do something like:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PageAdminForm
    # Plus many other stuff here (that I don't want to copy/paste in PlacePageAdmin to keep dry...)

class PlacePageAdmin(PageAdmin):
    form = PlacePageAdminForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return super(PlacePageAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = copy.deepcopy(super(PlacePageAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj))
        fieldsets.insert(0,
            ('Place', {
                'fields': (
                    ('address', 'postcode', 'town'),
                ),
            })
        )
        return fieldsets

    def queryset(self, request):
        return PlacePage.objects.filter(page_type=Page.PLACE)
```

But I can't make it work: I get a `u"Key 'address' not found in Form"` error when trying to access the PlacePageAdmin form page.

Has someone ever done such a thing?

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit - The forms code:

```
class PageAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Page

class PlacePageAdminForm(PageAdminForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PlacePage
```

Comment: Yes, you can. You are already doing it. but i think that you error is in PlacePageAdminForm form, not in your model admin subclass

Comment: Add your form class code.

Comment: Thanks for your answers: I edited my message to add the form classes code.

Comment: No idea on what's the matter with it?

Comment: how come the 2 forms point to different models? as i see it they should represent the same model

Comment: PlacePage inherits from Page, and has several other attributes, that's why the forms point to different models.

Comment: In fact, the problems comes from the get_fieldsets method, which I wrote in PlacePageAdmin class : PlacePageAdmin(self, request, obj=None):\ fieldsets = copy.deepcopy(super(PlacePageAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj))\ fieldsets.insert(0,('Place',{'fields':(('address', 'postcode', 'town'),),}))\ return fieldsets

Answer (score 1):

of course you can, this is basic python, even more you can create mixins you can add to your class inheritance list which may be more useful - as smaller and simpler examples of inheriting from multiple sources

error you are getting is connected with your forms, there are few things that could go wrong

- the most popular is definition of which fields in form.ModelForm are defined - those fields are specified in Meta class inside ModelForm class - there are problems with inheritance, so make sure that in inherited forms you will set it properly
- there may be a field that is not being defined in the second form or model - then your form inheritance can fail